# How can I combine PyQt4 and Tornado's event loops into one application?

Tags: python, bash, qt, pyqt, tornado

I am trying to program an application that runs a HTTP server as well as a GUI using Tornado and PyQt4 respectively.  I am confused about how to use these two event loops in parallel. Can this be done with the multiprocessing module? Should the HTTP server be run in a QtThread? Or is a bash script the best way to go to run both of these processes at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need a bash script. Probably simplest to write a PyQt application and have the application launch the web server. The server may be in a separate thread or process depending on your requirements, but I'd start by having a single thread as a first draft and splitting it out later.

Having the PyQt app as your main thread makes sense as your GUI is going to be responsible for user inputs (start/stop server, etc) and program outputs (server status, etc) and therefore it makes sense to make this the controlling thread with references to other objects or threads.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. My solution was to put tornado's event loop in a thread, and with signals execute a promise in the main (Qt's event) loop. See an example [here](https://gist.github.com/maartenbreddels/9a31e4025ef9cc0ee68a)

Comment: It would be easier to understand your answer, if you make the code more specific to the question.